# Trouble with portENTER_CRITICAL, vTaskSuspendAll in ESP32

Tags: esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I'm trying to surround the OTA https update in a critical section as I'm seeing other tasks pushing in and occasionally causing it to fail. The failure is a bcn_timeout on the WiFi.

The following code fragments don't work at all:

Attmept 1: (naive copy and paste from FreeRTOS docs)

```
taskENTER_CRITICAL();
esp_err_t rc = esp_https_ota(&config);
taskEXIT_CRITICAL();

Error :  
error: too few arguments to function 'vPortEnterCritical'     
#define portENTER_CRITICAL(mux)        vPortEnterCritical(mux)
```

Attmept 2: With a little help from google.

```
static portMUX_TYPE my_mutex;
vPortCPUInitializeMutex(&my_mutex);
taskENTER_CRITICAL(&my_mutex);
esp_err_t rc = esp_https_ota(&config);
taskEXIT_CRITICAL(&my_mutex);

Error : 
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU0).
```

Attempt 3: ...

```
vTaskSuspendAll();
esp_err_t rc = esp_https_ota(&config);
xTaskResumeAll();

Error : 
assert failed: xQueueGenericSend queue.c:775 (!( ( xTaskGetSchedulerState() == ( ( BaseType_t ) 0 ) ) && ( xTicksToWait != 0 ) ))
```

There are about 3 or 4 other tasks running that I'd rather just held fire while this completes, but obviously can't do anything that impedes the WiFi handlers from running.

Comment: Can't you just suspend other tasks using [`vTaskSuspend`](https://www.freertos.org/a00130.html)? (and resume with [`vTaskResume`](https://www.freertos.org/a00131.html))

Comment: @Mathieu Yeah, that was my thinking with the vTaskSuspendAll(), but it doesn't work?! It seems like I'm reading the docs, but I can't get the examples to run for some reason.

Comment: Why do you want to protect esp_https_ota at all ? I guess this won’t work because under the hood it’s a complex process which probably requires other tasks to run. 
Ensure in an other way that it’s just not invoked concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a critical section, the freeRTOS implementation for ESP32 MCUs require a 'spinlock' variable:

```
static portMUX_TYPE _spinlock = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

taskENTER_CRITICAL(&_spinlock);
// your critical code here
taskEXIT_CRITICAL(&_spinlock);
```

See the docs here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos_idf.html

Answer (score -1):

I have had similar problems with ESP32 and FreeRTOS. It appears that simply using `taskENTER_CRITICAL();` and `taskEXIT_CRITICAL();` from the FreeRTOS docs does not work because of the way FreeRTOS is modified for ESP32.

After much struggling I found that `vTaskSuspendAll();` and `xTaskResumeAll();` works but only as long as no delays are used. `vTaskDelay()` is supposed to allow a context switch. If it is called then it results in crashes.

For my application I managed to work around this problem by using a blocking delay function instead. If you find a better solution for the problem please post it here.

```
void blocked_delay_us(uint64_t number_of_us)
{
    uint64_t microseconds = (uint64_t)esp_timer_get_time();
    if (number_of_us) {
        while ((uint64_t)esp_timer_get_time() - microseconds < number_of_us)
            ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes no sense; guarding a critical task/section is very different than suspending & resuming a task. Yes in especially simple cases it could have 'a similar effect' as guarding a critical section but it is not economical and just not what it was meant for.